# Creating a vue app based on web-pack simple template using vue-cli 3.X

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm following a tutorial on a site about creating SPA. At some point it instructs to init the vue app this way:

```
vue init webpack-simple my-project
```

This, doesn't work for me. After 1 hour of searching through stack overflow I have found that for vue-cli 3.x (the version I'm using) the syntax has changed and now I must use:

```
vue create my-project
```

My question is, how do I init a project based on the webpack-simple template. This way of initing/creating a project asks some questions when the command is executed, but it says nothing about webpack. So, I'm a bit confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you really want webpack-simple in your project?

Comment: _"This, doesn't work for me."_ Could you explain more what issues are you running into?

Comment: Init the project and find for yourself. In cli 3.0 you have no strict template, but a wizard or standard bundle based on webpack that can be treated as "simple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vue cli 3 has moved on to implement a plugin based approach rather than template-based approach.

If you still want to create a project using `init` you can install a global bridge:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli-init
# vue init now works exactly the same as vue-cli@2.x
vue init webpack-simple my-project
```

Reference - [Pulling 2.x template](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#pulling-2-x-templates-legacy)

The project created by vue cli 3 uses webpack under the hood. The webpack configuration(webpack.config.js) is created at runtime. 
 You should use [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html) to configure webpack

Comment: ahhh, this is the confirmation I needed :). So, I will use the vue-cli 3.x way!. Thanks.